# Select from Access Database gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I am trying to set the string "testId" to a value selected from a database, but receive this error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

When I leave the code as is it works but when the lines aren't commented out i get the error

```
string testId = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void registerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|HorseDB.mdb");
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        OleDbCommand cmdSelect = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Users]([UserName], [UserSurname], [CellNumber], [Email], [Password])VALUES(@Name, @Surname, @Number, @Email, @Password)";
        //cmdSelect.CommandText = @"SELECT [UserId] FROM [Users] WHERE [Email] = @Email";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", registerNameTexbox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", registerSurnameTextbox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", registerNumbertextbox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", registerEmailTextbox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", registerPasswordTextbox.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //testId = cmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
        conn.Close();
        paymentSite();

    }
    catch (OleDbException fail)
    {
        errorLabel1.Text = fail.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that one of your values is empty. Try using `DBNull.Value` for such cases.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding your parameters to cmd but not to cmdSelect, even though your query for cmdSelect refers to @Email.

Add this line:

```
cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", registerEmailTextbox.Text);
```

Comment: `cmdSelect` is commented out. Also he's only executing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: He says "when the lines aren't commented out i get the error"

Comment: Oops, read over that line. You have the right answer here now. Though the OP should look at using [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar.aspx) on his select.

Comment: Thanx, that was the problem. But now the value of testId is always 0, any idea why that is?

Comment: Try ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery on cmdSelect.

Comment: Thanx, that sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're not adding the required **@Email parameter** for the cmdSelect command, like so:

```cs
cmdSelect.CommandText = @"SELECT [UserId] FROM [Users] WHERE [Email] = @Email";
Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", registerEmailTextbox.Text ?? DBNull.Value);
```

I've got a hunch your ExecuteNonQuery will work just fine after this.

Also, like @Uwe-Keim mentions in the comments, as a best practice you might want to check for null values in your textbox first. In the snippet I've appended this in a basic form using the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).